# Is there a way to find out the type of a variable in Netbeans?

Tags: java, xcode, swift, netbeans

When using Swift on Xcode, we can hold `option` and click on a variable's name to find out what type does the variable belong to. I was just wondering if there is a similar function in NetBeans while coding Java?

Comment: If you hold down [Command] and hover over the variable, it should give you more information (I think it's [Ctrl] in windows)

Comment: Thank you very much! It work! Do you want to write it as an answer so I can up vote and accept it?